# Difference between .createOrReplaceTempView & .as to create a temp view of a query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between createOrReplaceTempView and as function to alias a spark sql query to use if afterwards?

I am trying to understand the difference between these two methods.

```
val df = spark.sql("select x.*, y.* from person x inner join group y on x.group_key = y.group_key")

df.as("aliasview")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempview")
```

Answer (score 0):

createOrReplaceTempView creates (or replaces if that view name already exists) a lazily evaluated "view" that you can then use like a hive table in Spark SQL.
But the same you can't do with "SPARK Dataframe Alias AS"

Comment: do you mean i cannot do the as i performed in the OP?